# is there anything that handles web page refreshing in flask?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, socket.io

When I open the page, threads are created and, unfortunately, when the page is refreshed, the threads are created again and again and I want the threads that were created to be closed when the page is refreshed. but I haven't found anything that responds to page refresh. The disconnect function does not always work

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    user_id = request.sid
    start_chart_threads(user_id)

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    user_id = request.sid
    if user_id in user_threads:
        for chart_number in range(1, 4):
            if chart_number in user_threads[user_id] and user_threads[user_id][chart_number].is_alive():
                user_threads[user_id][chart_number].stop()
                user_threads[user_id][chart_number].join()
        del user_threads[user_id]
```

Comment: maybe in `connect` you should run code similar to code from `disconnect`